# css content property forces a clear when set to ""?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

This is a strange CSS issue that I'm hoping someone can shed some light on...

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and I'm seeing some very odd float/clearing behaviour. I have a right floated div and a form-horizontal in the main content. The second form field seems to clear below the floated div for no good reason. Going through all the HTML elements and the CSS declarations it's a strange property that is causing this to happen. I have reduced it down to a single CSS declaration:

```
 .control-group::before, .form-horizontal .control-group::after {
   display: table;
   content: "";
   line-height: 0;
 }
```

Specifically, the content: ""; If you disable this one declaration, it floats up with the first field and all is well.

I have created a JS fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/whiteatom/UJ89p/1/embedded/result/

With the source code: http://jsfiddle.net/whiteatom/UJ89p/1/

Is this by design? W3 spec? Is this specific to only some browsers (tested in Chrome, Safari and FF on MacOS)? What is the Bootstrap team trying to accomplish with this empty string property? Can I override it without editing the bootstrap CSS files?

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this by design?

Yes.

> W3 spec?

[Here it is.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content) An empty string is still considered content; if you want to completely prevent a box from being generated, you need to use `content: none` instead. Without modifying the Bootstrap files, you should be able to just add the following rule to your own stylesheet (overriding the `content: ""` declaration):

```
/* Single-colon pseudo-elements for consistency with Bootstrap's IE8 compat */
.form-horizontal .control-group:before, .form-horizontal .control-group:after {
    content: none;
}
```

Note that the float is being cleared because the `::after` pseudo-element is being used as a clearfix. The `clear` declaration is residing in a separate rule elsewhere in the Bootstrap stylesheet:

```
.form-horizontal .control-group:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

By adding the proper `content: none` declaration it will prevent the pseudo-element from being rendered at all, thereby preventing clearance.

> Is this specific to only some browsers (tested in Chrome, Safari and FF on MacOS)? What is the Bootstrap team trying to accomplish with this empty string property?

[Some very old versions of Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Opera don't support `content: none`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/content#compatibilitysection), and instead incorrectly treat `content: ""` (with the empty string) as having no content. The versions that do support `content: none` treat both values correctly, as does IE8 and later.

I'm guessing by using the empty string, they're trying to account for these older browsers. If that's the case, it should have been overridden with `content: none` so newer versions will use the correct value, like this:

```
.form-horizontal .control-group:before, .form-horizontal .control-group:after {
    display: table;
    content: "";
    content: none;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

If so — and that's my best guess — then a bug report may be in order.

Comment: I don't see how the clear is by design.. the empty string can't force the div to drop below the floated div can it? there is no clear, no width? If I put a space in the div, it won't drop below the floated div.. so why is an empty string causing that?

Comment: @whiteatom: An empty string will still generate a box, so if that box is supposed to provide clearance, it will clear.

Comment: doesn't a box require a clear declaration to clear? I can put an h1 in there and it won't clear... this is very frustrating. I just can't for the life of me see how the original declaration has this effect. I'd like to understand the why here - because what you're saying seems to contradict my CSS knowledge.

Comment: @whiteatom: Yes; I found that `clear` declaration in another rule, in the next line: `.form-horizontal .control-group:after{clear:both;}` (line 328 of the minified CSS file)

Comment: PS.. your suggestion of the new declaration does fix the problem.. Ahh.. ok.. that makes more sense.. So the .control-group:after applies to what ever block is after the control-group, and they are creating an empty block to trigger that rule. Interesting way of putting a clear after an element. I guess adding a rule to override that one would be the easiest way to fix this - thanks!

Comment: @whiteatom: Yep, it's known as a clearfix. (And IMO one of the worst practices in CSS - a hack, if you will.)