# How to use Pseudo-Elements : before & :after to create end caps

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm attempting to use the Pseudo-Element :before and :after to add a end cap look to the ends of `div` elements.

I've tried a few things but I'm not getting it for some reason.

With the CSS below I've attempted to add a box, or just anything to show up to get me a starting place to work with, but even the CSS below does not show up.

```css
.horDim {position:absolute;left:5px;right:5px;top:10%;height:15px;border-top:1px dotted black;}
.horDimTxt {position:absolute;left:25%;bottom:0;}

.horDim:before {

    position:absolute;left:10px;top:10px;

    width:25px;

    height:25px;

    background-color:red;
}
```

The div that I'm using to create the line between the vertical bars looks like so.

```
<div class="horDim"><span class="horDimTxt">10 1/2</span></div>
```

Here is a snapshot of what it looks like now and in the snapshot lower image in an example of what the end caps need to look like.

[image: Snapshot]

**Any suggestions on how to do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `content: ''` attribute on your psudo-elements.  This attribute is required for it do display.

```
.horDim:before {
    content: ''
    position:absolute;left:10px;top:10px;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

The reason is found in the [W3C spec for the content attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-content):

> Initial:      normal (none)
>
> none: The pseudo-element is not generated.

More info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067918/why-do-pseudo-elements-require-a-content-property)

Comment: Yep, that's it. got any idea how to do the angles?

Comment: @AlumCloud.Com You can use css border hacks to generate borders.  I've been really meaning to redo this example, but I have one that uses html elements to create border hacks here: http://jsfiddle.net/W6uak  NOTE: I do not condone or endors the use of non-semantic HTML to do this.  Use pseudo-elements if possible. :P