# How to add ::after in the HTML link tag

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

There is a CSS effect for the `::after` element. For example:

```
.wrapper a:hover:after, footer.main-footer a:hover:after {
   background:#ff0000;
}
```

And in the Chrome developer console, I notice that there is some link tag has `::after` inside, that will show the effect

```
<a href="test.com" data-term="event">Event::after</a>
```

While some does not have it

```
<a class="back-to-portfolio" href="test2.com">All</a>
```

That element does not show the effect. The problem is, how to add the `::after` to the link tag or under what conditions the `::after` will show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically for the `:after` element to work or be present, the entire selector should be matched. In the below snippet you can see how only the `a` element which is a descendant of `.wrapper` element or a descendant of `footer.main-footer` element gets the `:after` element. The other `a` which is outside both the `div.wrapper` and `footer.main-footer` does not get the `:after` element.

Another thing to note is that [pseudo-elements are generated only if `content` property is specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067918/why-do-pseudo-elements-require-a-content-property). So, in the below snippet, the `:after` element is generated only when the `a` is hovered.

```css
.wrapper a:hover:after,
footer.main-footer a:hover:after {
  background: #ff0000;
}
/* just for demo */

.wrapper,
footer {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
}
.wrapper a:hover:after,
footer.main-footer a:hover:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: ''; /* this is important */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <a href="test.com" data-term="event">Event::after</a>
</div>
<footer class='main-footer'>
  <a href="test.com" data-term="event">Event::after</a>
</footer>

<a class="back-to-portfolio" href="test2.com">All</a>
```

On the other hand, in the following snippet the `:after` is present even when `a` is not hovered.

```css
.wrapper a:after,
footer.main-footer a:after {
  background: #ff0000;
}
/* just for demo */

.wrapper,
footer {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
}
.wrapper a:after,
footer.main-footer a:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: ''; /* this is important */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <a href="test.com" data-term="event">Event::after</a>
</div>
<footer class='main-footer'>
  <a href="test.com" data-term="event">Event::after</a>
</footer>

<a class="back-to-portfolio" href="test2.com">All</a>
```

---

Coming to your question on why some anchor/link tags have the `:after` whereas some other others don't, the reason should be because the anchor/link tag which doesn't have the `:after` element does not match the selector which sets the `content` property.

(*I assume the content property must be getting set somewhere in your page because you mentioned that it is showing up for some elements.*)

Comment: Great . very detail , that means I need to make up a class for those link those not have ::after and set content: '' for that class?

Comment: Yes, that or give their parents the `wrapper` class :)

Answer (score 2):

Add `content` property like this:

```
.wrapper a:hover:after, footer.main-footer a:hover:after {
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
   background:#ff0000;
   content: "";
   display: inline-block;
}
```