# How to do something to appear before or after in a HTML division tag?

Tags: css

Actually, I have a `div` tag and I run code like below:

```
<div class="navbar-text">someText</div>

...

.navbar-text:before {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #f00;
}
```

But I cannot see the red square. How can I make it appear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do the :before and :after pseudo-elements require a 'content' property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067918/why-do-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-require-a-content-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```css
.navbar-text:before {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  content: '';
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-text"> Some Text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

::before or :: after will not work without a `content` property. It may be empty but it has to be there.

```css
.navbar-text:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-text">someText</div>
```