# border-bottom not working in pseudo selector section: after HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, frontend

My code is below but it is not working. I want to add a dotted line after each section which has width 100%.

```
section::after {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted red;
}
```

Comment: show us the rest of your code

Comment: Pseudo elements require the ['content' property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067918/why-do-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-require-a-content-property).

Comment: true, but won't give you a line across the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this works for you :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    section {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    section::after {
      content: " ";
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      border: 2px solid red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <section>
    <h1>WWF</h1>
    <p>The World Wide Fund for Nature (WWF) is an international organization working on issues regarding the conservation, research and restoration of the environment, formerly named the World Wildlife Fund. WWF was founded in 1961.</p>
  </section>
```

Comment: thanks everyone for your responses. Specialy @Abhishek Pakhare, thanks it worked.

Comment: You most welcome  I am happy this worked for you. All the best.

Answer (score 2):

just remove ::after  borders apply to elements. adding content won't create a line across the page.  Not sure why this was voted down.  It works and is pretty straight forward.

```css
section {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be `ul` will be work for you,

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Name:</span></li>
    <li><span>Age:</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li {
    border-bottom: 2px dotted #ccc;
}
```

I created a demo for you in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45xfku3c/5/)