# :pseudo CSS rule not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, magento

I have a CSS rule which is working in all browsers but IE.  When I check it in the IE inspector I can see that the rule is not being applied.

```
.wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Any idea why this rule is not being applied in IE?

I'm testing on IE 11, 10 & 9.   I'm working on a Magento app.

Comment: Is it working in other browsers? Your pseudo-element has no content.

Comment: What is the expected result? your :after has no content, so what do other browsers display? Seems like you did not include some actual code in the question.

Comment: @Rob: An empty string is in fact considered content. "No content" would be `content: none`. While some older browsers did have issues distinguishing `none` from the empty string, IE is not one of those browsers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656098/css-content-property-forces-a-clear-when-set-to/13656136#13656136

Comment: @rob, yes it works in chrome, safari & firefox

Comment: @BoltClock I'm not sure that's the same thing. The spec says 'none' doesn't generate the element while, presumably, anything else will generate the element but that element would contain a string and, in this case, no newline and empty content so, therefore, no inline box? Don't know.

Comment: @Rob: Put simply, an empty string results in an empty inline box, which is not the same as *no* box. If you made it a block, or a table, the same would apply - the box is empty, but it's there.

Comment: Does using some other value for `display` help? Are you in quirks mode?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by re-writing the css rule to:

```
.wrapper:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
```

I don't understand why the previous rule did not work on IE, while it worked in all other  browsers.  The previous rule was being inherited from the Magento RWD theme.

Also, it seems that the IE inspector crosses out all :after rules, which is misleading as some of them are actually working on the page.